# How visualise the vote margin on map using r?

Tags: r

I wonder if anybody can help me. I am a new user in R and have been stacked now (( Can anybody help me to visualise the Leave:Remain vote margin by Constituency using a diverging colour scheme. the code I am using is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

install.packages("parlitools") 
library(parlitools)

data_gb <- bes_2019 %>%
  filter(region != "Northern Ireland")
voting <- data_gb %>%
  select(constituency_name, region, ons_const_id,leave_hanretty, remain_hanretty, constituency_name) %>% 
  group_by(ons_const_id, region, leave_hanretty, remain_hanretty, constituency_name) 
 
voting  <- cons_outline %>%
  inner_join(voting , by=c("pcon19cd"="ons_const_id"))
  
voting %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill=leave_hanretty, remain_hanretty), colour="#eeeeee", size=0.01)+
  coord_sf(crs=27700, datum=NA) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette=7,"BrBG") + 
  scale_color_gradient(low = "light", high = "dark")
```

I am getting the following results:

[image: the recieved result]

But I my result should look like:
[image: Final result]

Comment: Hi Liz. Do you have a link to the data set so we can reproduce the plot?

Comment: Hard to show this without your actual data, but [`scale_fill_gradient2(...)`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/scale_colour_gradient2) is designed for this. Set `mid='white'` and `midpoint=50` and `high`/`low` to the appropriate colors from the image you provided.

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron the json file is  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vypuPy9nPQbPt-tMnT5FmkHbzuXd67tb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Liz. I've got that now, thanks. How about `data_gb` ?

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron the installation of the package (install.packages("parlitools") will install the dataset bes_2019, from which I have created data_gb, using the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to do this is to calculate difference between leave and remain and then cut it into intervals. Then you will have factor column and ggplot should display it with diverging colors.

```
hanretty_class = cut(
  voting$leave_hanretty - voting$remain_hanretty, breaks = 5, labels = c(
    'Heavy Remain'
    ,'Moderate Remain'
    ,'Neutral'
    ,'Moderate Leave'
    ,'Heavy Leave'
  ))

voting <- cbind(voting, hanretty_class)
```